# how to find same element in both array using single loop?

Tags: java

I am getting output as FIVE FOUR THREE which is correct, but how to convert it by using only one loop?

public class DemoTwo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] inputArray1 = {"ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "FOUR"};
      
    String[] inputArray2 = {"THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "FOUR"};

    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<inputArray1.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<inputArray2.length;j++) {
            if(inputArray1[i].equals(inputArray2[j]))
                set.add(inputArray1[i]);
                    
        }
    }
    System.out.print(set);
    
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean "without in-built functions"?

Comment: Right now you are checking to see if the values are the same, at the same index.  That is why its outputting 5,6.  If you want to see if ANY value of one array is the same as ANY value of the other array, you probably want 2 loops.

Comment: Why do you check arrays lengths if the expected output is 5,6,7?

Comment: The code presented directly uses at least three things that could be considered "built-in functions": the nullary constructor of class `HashSet`, method `HashSet.add()`, and method `System.out.println()`.  Behind the scenes, some of these certainly use additional methods of various classes, too.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is that you are checking not only if the element is present in both, but is at the same index in both arrays.

In order to reduce search time complexity to O(n) and get the correct result you first have to add all elements of the first array in a `Set` and then loop over the other, checking the `Set` to see if it was present in the first. A `HashSet` will allow looking up values in O(1) and therefore reduce time complexity of otherwise needed nested loops O(n^2) to O(n).

E.g.

```java
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class DemoTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        

        int[] inputArrayOne = {5,4,6,7,2,5,4,9};
        int[] inputArrayTwo = {5,0,6,6,5,7,8,3};
        
        Set<Integer> arrayOneSet = intSetOf(inputArrayOne);
        Set<Integer> unionSet = intSetOf();
        
        for (int i : inputArrayTwo) {
            if (arrayOneSet.contains(i)) {
                unionSet.add(i);
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(unionSet);
        
    }
    
    private static Set<Integer> intSetOf(int ...ints) {
         Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
         
         for (int i : ints) {
            set.add(i);
         }
         
         return set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
int[] inputArrayTwo = {5,4,6,7,2,5,4,9};
int[] inputArrayOne = {5,0,6,6,5,7,8,3};

// Create a set from second list.  
// If that's considered a "built-in method", just iterate over elements and add them manually
Set<Integer> set2 = Arrays.stream(inputArrayTwo).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
Set<Integer> commonElementsSet = new HashSet<>();

for (int i = 0; i < inputArrayOne.length; i++) {
    if(set2.contains(inputArrayOne[i])){
        commonElementsSet.add(inputArrayOne[i]);
    }
}

System.out.println(commonElementsSet);
```

Output:

```
[5, 6, 7]
```